# Determining the similarity between two random number generators

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, random, statistics

Suppose that I have two random number genertors RNG-A and RNG-B, such that:

- They both produce random, non-infinite floating point numbers when called
- I can call the generators repeatedly and generate as many random numbers as I like
- The random numbers generated are independent and identically distributed (i.e. the output of the RNGs is independent of everything they have previously produced)
- I can't guarantee anything else about the shape of the distribution

I would like to obtain a *measure of how similar* the two random distributions are, and ideally use this to determine if they appear to producing the same distribution.

What is is the best algorithm for doing this?

Comment: Better asked on http://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: If the numbers they produce are identically distributed, then you know the shape of the distribution you expect.

Comment: @Space_Cowboy - not true - i.i.d. this is a property that random distributions can have, but it doesn't tell you much about the distribution otherwise. For example, both uniform random numbers and normal random numbers can have this property

Comment: @KennyTM: thanks! didn't know that existed - will try it out but either way I'm keen to hear from StackOverflow since a) I'm after an implementable algorithm rather than a theoretical statistics viewpoint b) there isn't much traffic there....

Comment: @mikera: A number of [similar](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random-generation) questions have already been answered at Stats SE.

Comment: This doesn't look like any random number generators I'm familiar with, but it is identical to statistics problems with samples from two populations.

Comment: @mikera: Thanks for explaining, I learned something today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In randomize algorithms main concern is in Mean and Variance, also Mode and some other factors are important, but you can generate too many number and compare their related Mean and Variance, and check their similarity. Also you can find relation ship of them with other functions (like Gaussian function).
but the most famous test for your case is:

- [Kolmogorov–Smirnov test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test)

Also you can use **chi square test** if you want to have a finite numbers (for example **generated number** % **big prime number**)

Comment: thanks - it looks like the Kolmogorov Smirnov approach may be just what I need

Comment: @mikera, I think so, I'd read it in http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/taocp.html. I don't know which volume :D

Comment: Mean and variance are useful statistics but don't necessarily give a good picture of a distribution.

Comment: @walkytalky, All common distributions are based on variation of this things, but if you have any other idea, I'll be happy to learn something new.

Comment: @AlixAxel, we say it mood, count of an item with most frequency.

Comment: Good to know, I've always seen written as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics).

Comment: @AlixAxel, Good to know it, thanks for link, so we were wrong :), but actually I never used it in applications.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll find your answers [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.rice.edu%2F~johnmc%2Fcomp528%2Flecture-notes%2FLecture22.pdf&rct=j&q=random%20generator%20%20distribution%20testing%20chisquare&ei=4inQTNOiHM6s8Ab_1fClBw&usg=AFQjCNFuZIR1ZxSZmkWnOZUPeufDlQizfA&sig2=b3ICFGwUxTP1OFQk0D9eVQ&cad=rja).

Excerpts:

*Testing Random Number Generators

Does observed data satisfies a particular distribution?

• Chi-square test

• Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

• Serial correlation test

• Two-level tests

• K-distributivity

• Serial test

• Spectral test

.....*

Another section:

*Serial Correlation Test

• Test if 2 random variables are dependent

    —is their covariance non-zero?

    – if so, dependent. converse not true.*

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

Because you cannot make a statement about the either distribution, you may need a non-parametric test to compare the (unknown) distributions. You can use a K-S test, but when you look at applications, look under non-parametric statistics.

Answer (score -1):

When you say compare two distributions, it's not really clear how detailed an answer you want. For example, consider these two sequences:

```
RNG-A: 1111100000
RNG-B: 1010101010
```

Since the means and variances are identical, it would pass the [Kolmogorov–Smirnov test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) with flying colours. However, it's **obvious** that RNG-A and RNG-B generate sequences with different characteristics. Depending on your situation, this may or may not be problem. As long as you know the risks involved, you can make an informed decision.

If you really want to make sure that the generators are identical, then take a look at the link provided in belisarius' answer. However, this compares a RNG to a **known** distribution. In your case, the you don't know either distribution. Although I suppose you could simulate RNG-A enough times as an approximation to get going.

Another useful thing to look at is the Diehard tests. See the answers to this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30/) at the stats.SE.

Comment: I think I'd be happy for these two to be declared identical since I know the RNGs are independent and identically distributed (i.e. there is no serial correlation). hence if they come up with the same frequency distribution they are identical.